# can Veracode be taught to accept mitigations that it does not yet recognize

Tags: xss, static-analysis

Veracode (http://www.veracode.com/) has certain parameter encoding libraries that it trusts.  Others are labeled as flaws. If I'm satisfied with another method of parameter encoding that is meant to stop XSS, can I tell Veracode to stop listing uses of it as a flaw?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can group all these instances and mark them as *false positives*. I would think Veracode provides an option to write a custom rule, so it ignores these instances when they occur.